# Why would a file have NO color code?

Tags: centos, ls, colors, less

Two files in one of my directories are rendered as gray on PuTTy.

Running `ls -l --color=always | less` shows a list with most file names preceded by `ESC[01;32m`

But those two files do not. The filename is preceded by the timestamp, just as in a regular ls -l command. What causes this?

Comment: Can you show us? (an image is appropriate in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably nothing special about it. On my system Debian (no customisation), most files are un-coloured. The ones that are coloured are: directories, symbolic links, executable, device-files, named-pipes, and a few others such as archives (tar, zip, etc.).

Comment: Actually, the source of confusion is more likely file-permissions (executable vs non-executable).

Comment: It looks like executable-vs-not accounted for the difference in my case. Thanks!